# Send object to mvc controller using ajax

Tags: c#, ajax

I am passing multiple parameters in an object and then passing it to a Method in the controller. It is hitting the method but it's not carrying the data to be sent from ajax call to the method . When I am going to check object of the model it displays null. SO can I send the data in such a way or should I try another approach?
Thanks in advance Please help me.
Here is my code.

```js
var Color = [], Material = [], Size = [], FinishingType = [], Style = [];
        $('.productFilterLabelList .filterList').on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function () {
            debugger;
           
            var Main = {};
            var filterType = $(this).parents('.productFilterLabelList').find('.hdn-filter-type').val();
            var filterTypeID = $(this).val();
            var ischeked = $(this).is(':checked');
            if (ischeked) {
                if (filterType == 'color') {
                    Color.push(filterTypeID);
                }
                else if (filterType == 'size') {
                    Size.push(filterTypeID);
                }
                else if (filterType == 'finsih') {
                    FinishingType.push(filterTypeID);
                }
                else if (filterType == 'material') {
                    Material.push(filterTypeID)
                }
                else {
                    Style.push(filterTypeID);
                }
            }
            else {
                alert('hello');
                if (filterType == 'color') {
                    Color.pop(filterTypeID);
                }
                else if (filterType == 'size') {
                    Size.pop(filterTypeID);
                }
                else if (filterType == 'finsih') {
                    FinishingType.pop(filterTypeID);
                }
                else if (filterType == 'material') {
                    Material.pop(filterTypeID)
                }
                else {
                    Style.pop(filterTypeID);
                }
            }
            Main = {
                Color: Color,
                Size: Size,
                FinishingType: FinishingType,
                Material: Material,
                Style: Style
            }
            console.log(Main);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/SearchByAllFilterTags',
                type: "Get",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: '{Main:' +JSON.stringify(Main)+' }',
                success: function (results) {
                   
                }
            })
        });
        
 public ActionResult SearchByAllFilterTags(ProductFilterViewModel Main)
    {
        return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }`public class ProductFilterViewModel
{
    public int[] Color { get; set; }
    public int[] Material { get; set; }
    public int[] Size { get; set; }
    public int[] FinishingType { get; set; }
    public int[] Style { get; set; }
    public int[] Pattern { get; set; }
    //public string FilterText { get; set; }
    //public List<ProductFilterViewModel> FilterTextList { get; set; }
}`
```

Comment: Did you try simply passing the Main itself?

Comment: Yes i 've tried it before its hitting controller method but unable to find data in model object into the method.

Comment: just remove json.stringify so your code must be like this { 'Main': Main},

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to stringify your object. Just pass your `Main` object:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/SearchByAllFilterTags',
    type: "Get",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    data: Main,
    success: function (results) {
    }
})
```

#### Edit:

If your arrays are empty in the action method try to add `traditional: true` to `ajax` settings

Comment: passing simply the main object but still not getting the data at controller it still dislaying null.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to stringify. Use this format:

```
 Main = {
            "Color": [{Color}],
            "Size": [{Size}],
            "FinishingType": [{FinishingType}],
            "Material": [{Material}],
            "Style": [{Style}]
        }
        console.log(Main);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/SearchByAllFilterTags',
            type: "Get",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: Main,
            success: function (results) {

            }
        })
    });
```

As long as you didn't add quotation marks in your json data, your data will not pass.

This will work if your model at the controller is matched.

Comment: model is same but still not getting the data at model.

Comment: remove content type from the ajax request

Comment: yes its hitting the method and 1 array in model but its not actual value which i have pushed into the varriable it shows 0 in array

Comment: I think it displays the array index no instead of value

Comment: this is for you to check the data, once the ajax hits the method the main problem solved

Comment: Ok thank you but the ajax was already hitting the method . There was a problem with data anyway Thanks you so much.